# How do I run a program within a Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a Tkinter app that incorporates the use of a touchscreen keyboard and will be run off a Raspberry Pi. I found an onscreen keyboard called Matchbox-keyboard.

My question is: is there a way to "embed" this keyboard into a GUI created by Tkinter? I would like to embed the keyboard so it opens at the bottom of the parent window.

So far all I can come up with is:

```
subprocess.Popen(['matchbox-keyboard'])
```

which works, but it opens in a separate window.

Below is a sample of my code. Keep in mind that I haven't coded the `get()` functions for the text fields yet, or any of the other functions for that matter.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess

process_one = subprocess.Popen(['matchbox-keyboard'])

root = Tk()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side = BOTTOM)
root.title("PinScore")
L0 = Label(root, text = "Welcome to PinScore!")
L0.pack(side = TOP)

L1 = Label(root, text = "Initials:")
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

L2 = Label(root, text = "High Score:")
L2.pack( side = RIGHT)
E2 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E2.pack(side = RIGHT)

B = Button(bottomframe, text = "Enter High Score")
B.pack(side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no, but there is hope, and it will require a fair amount of work.
 According to [the github](https://github.com/xlab/matchbox-keyboard) it is made in gtk. Then the question becomes "Can I put a gtk object in my tkinter program?". To my knowledge (and a lot of Googling) there is no way to embed gtk features in the Tkinter. You may want to try pyGTK instead, because these would be much easier to integrate (I know that it is possible). I might suggest that before you get any further in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply user3724292! After reviewing gtk I believe I will be able to recreate what I did in tkinter, even better to boot! But that still leaves the question as to how I would accomplish this task. Is the source code available on github? If so would I just copy and paste the code in a container at the bottom of the screen? Once again I'm a Noob! I have some experience with C++/arduino and very minor html skills. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use PyGTK! The [github](https://github.com/xlab/matchbox-keyboard) contains the gtk source and you can do it that way.

Actually, looking more at the github, you may not need to do that. The keyboard allows for command-line options, such as `-v,--override            Absolute positioning on the screen` and `-g,--geometry <HxW.y.x>  Specify keyboard's geometry` (taken from the github). You won't be able to control the z position (as in whether it is above or below your window).

If you truely want the embeded feeling, the github also says that you can embed it in gtk and points to `examples/matchbox-keyboard-gtk-embed.c` this might be what your looking for. You probably can translate it to pygtk. I found [this](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html), which talks about XEMBED. And I found [this too](http://perezdecastro.org/old/embedding-widgets-from-other-processes-with-pygtk.html) which actually embeds something. Finally, I'll point you to [the docs for gtk.socket](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtksocket.html).